# Characterization of hierarchically clustered graphs

Tags: graph-theory, trees, clustering

There is a strong relationship between (rooted) trees and hierarchically clustered graphs as can be seen here:

[image]

The tree - consisting of circles (green = the root, blue, red, black = the leaves) and thin lines - can  be seen as the result of a [hierarchical cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) of the graph consisting of the black circles and thick lines. Hierarchically clustered graphs can be defined as those graphs for which an appropriately defined hierarchical cluster analysis yields a (non-trivial) tree.

Trees are very elegantly defined and characterized as graphs that are connected and have no cycles. But how can their companions - the hierarchically clustered graphs - be characterized in a similar elegant way, or characterized at all (next to their definition above)?

Comment: I don't know if I can help with graph theoretic things, but if you made the sides slightly longer the current projection would look very much like the first few iterations of a Sierpinski triangle.

Comment: That 's because it's a strictly ternary tree.

Comment: But it is almost cooler as it is because it looks like the previous layer has a hexagon where the new layer has triangles, at least for blue and red layers.